# Large subsets of groups with no solution to linear equations

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

Is there a (sequence of finite nonabelian) group(s) $G$ and a (sequence of corresponding) subset(s) $S \subseteq G$, $|S| = |G|^{1-o(1)}$, such that there is no solution to $xy^{-1}z = zy^{-1}x$ with distinct $x,y,z \in S$?

(The question was asked previously with the stronger $|S| = \Omega(|G|)$. As was observed by mathworker21, taking x,y,z to be an arithmetic progression solves the above equation, so Roth's theorem gives a negative answer).

Comment: you have -y on both sides

Comment: Indeed, both sides are identical after rearranging, so I assume there is a typo. Which equation did you mean?

Comment: Perhaps the group may be nonabelian, despite the additive notation? This would make the equation nontrivial.

Comment: In multiplicative notation, easier to read for most of us: the equality is $$xy^{-1}z=zy^{-1}x.$$ Also given the $\Omega(-)$, the question is not about "a group", but "a sequence of finite groups of order tending to infinity". Also "distinct" means "pairwise distinct".

Comment: Indeed the question is about nonabelian groups, and about a sequence of groups. Thank you for your corrections.

Comment: A $3$-term arithmetic progression works: $x=a,y=ab,z=abb$ for $a,b \in G$. I don't know if Roth's theorem holds in arbitrary groups, but I'm sure someone does.

Comment: You are right! And I think that Roth's theorem holds for arbitrary groups (at least if they have odd order), since the Ruzsa-Szemeredi proof carries through. I would now revise my question as: Is there $S \subseteq G$, $|S| = |G|^{1-o(1)}$, with no non-trivial solution to $xy^{-1}z = zy^{-1}x$?

Comment: thanks everyone for all the clarifications. OP should edit the question to put in the full specification as in your last comment.

Comment: Indeed, Solymosi (Roth-type theorems in finite groups, 2013) has shown that as long as $G$ has a large index Sylow 2-subgroup then any positive density subset contains three distinct elements of the form $a,ba,b^2a$.

Comment: Unless I miscalculated, $\langle x,y,z\mid xy^{-1}z=zy^{-1}x\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}^2*\mathbb{Z}$, which of course has many homomorphisms to any group. This means that non-trivial solutions to this equation will be very common.

Comment: extending @mathworker21 's idea: if $x = a,y= ab^n, z= ab^m$, then $xy^{-1}z = ab^{m-n} = zy^{-1}x$. thus, such a set $S$ must satisfy $|S\cap C|<3$ for each coset $C$ that is generated by a single element. hence, it is necessary that each element $g\in G$ has $|\langle g\rangle| =|G|^{o(1)}$.